# Background color to floating label in material design in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, material-design, android-textinputlayout

I want to add background color to floating label in material design in android for edit text. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

     <EditText
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="Hiiiii"
         android:id="@+id/editText"/>

 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

in your style.xml

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/Color Name</item> 
<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
<!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
<item name="colorAccent">@color/Color Name</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/Color Name</item>
<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/Color Name</item>
```

or

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Edit : It is not possible to change only the lable background as your editext is wrapped inside TextInputLayout if you try to set background the output will be similar to .
[image: this]

Comment: This will change the floating hint/label color not its background.

Comment: do you want to change only the hint background??

Comment: Yes. I want to change the background color only.

Comment: I think this is not possible beacause your edittext is wrapped inside TextInputLayout if you change the background for TextInputLayout it would affect the edit text also